# R subscript out of bound error - for loop over custom function

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I've written a function to simulate genetic drift and i'm wanting to loop it over various values of t (number of generations), however whenever I do this I get the following error:

```
locifreq<-runif(49, .4, 0.8)

gen<-1:100
for (i in 1:length(gen)){
  pop[i]<-lapply(locifreq,wright.fisher,3000,200,gen[i])
}
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = rbinom(1, 2 * N, prob = k[i - 1,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I think it's because my function isn't able to generate the appropriate matrices or it's can't access the matrix within the list (though I may be completely wrong!), however I'm not sure how to fix this, as each attempt results in an incorrect number of subscripts.

The code for my function is below

```
wright.fisher<-function(p,Ne,nsim,t){
  N <-Ne/2
  NA1 <- 2*N*p 
  NA2 <- 2*N*(1-p)
  k <- matrix(0, nrow = t, ncol = nsim)
  k[1,] <- rep(NA1, nsim) 
  for (j in 1:nsim) {
    for (i in 2:t) {
      k[i, j] <- rbinom(1, 2*N, prob = k[i-1, j] / (2*N))  
    }
  }
  k <- as.matrix(k/(2*N)) 
  t(k)
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: In the first loop, where i=1, You are passing gen[1]=t=1, and k is defined as 1 row and nsim columns yet you are trying to assign a value to k[2,1] which does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is reproduced with this portion of your code:

```
wright.fisher(locifreq[1], 3000, 200, 1)
```

The particular step that causes the subscript out of bounds error is the assignment of `k[i,j]` in line 9 on the first step through the loop. At that point, `i` is 2, `j` is 1. You can typically extend an object by assigning it to an index beyond its range, but you can't do that with an array in a manner that would require changing the number of dimensions. (which is what `k[2,1]` does at that moment, since it's a matrix of 1 row and 200 columns).

```
k <- matrix(1:200, 1)
k[2,1] <- 5
# Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 2, 1, value = 5) : subscript out of bounds
```

You can solve this by having your function initialize the matrix to have the correct number of dimensions. Make your changes to line 5 of your function

```
k <- matrix(0, nrow = max(2, t), ncol = nsim)
```

I chose `max(2, t)` because that is what the requirements of your nested for loop impose: `for (i in 2:t)`. It completes, addressing the question in your post, but please confirm that it produces the behavior you want.

Additionally, there are a number of not particularly efficient idioms in your code, but that's another question.

#### How to Debug in R

If you want to know how to debug something like this... I'm thinking of writing a tutorial on how to use the browser (it comes up frequently here). Add a line at the top of your function body, `browser()`. Then when you try to run the browser, it will pull it up in the browser, which will allow you to step through the function one statement at a time. Enter `help` to see how to navigate it.  In RStudio, keep on eye on the Environment tab to see what values the variable holds. Notice that you can evaluate any R expression while you're in the browser. This will help you check on what you think is causing problems.

Comment: This works relatively well, however unfortunately when I loop the function it doesn't iterate over every level of locifreq. 
The outcome should ideally give me a list containing gen number of lists - each containing 49 matrices

Comment: @MolEcologist29 That's a different question :) (rather than how do I fix the subscript out of bounds error). That problem has been resolved, but as I said, you need to confirm after resolving this error, your function gives you the behavior you want. Have you tried using the browser to try to answer your new question? If you'd like to post the new problem as an additional question, I'm sure we could help with it. I'd encourage you to try out the browser, though!

Answer (score 0):

Your Wright-Fisher simulation looks a bit complicated, but I don't know what you are simulating, so maybe that is correct. I will use a simpler version and just sample the gene frequency in the next generation given the frequency in this and the effective population size.

```
wf <- function(f, Ne) {
    rbinom(1, 2*Ne, prob = f) / (2*Ne)
}
```

The real issue is the table and how to index into it. If `wf` computes one frequency given `f` and `Ne`, and you want `no_sims` simulations over `no_gen` generations, you can build a `no_gens x no_sims` table and fill it up, such that rows correspond to generations and columns correspond to independent simulations. It can look like this:

```
no_sims <- 5
no_gens <- 4
Ne <- 10000

locifreq <- runif(5, .4, 0.8)
sims <- matrix(NA, ncol = no_sims, nrow = no_gens)
sims[1,] <- runif(5, .4, 0.8) # first generation
for (gen in 2:no_gens) {
    sims[gen,] <- sapply(sims[gen-1,], FUN = wf, Ne = Ne)
}
```

The result with these (small) parameters look like this:

```
> sims
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.5948922 0.7185469 0.6290239 0.4303951 0.5701607
[2,] 0.5987000 0.7108500 0.6254000 0.4270500 0.5754000
[3,] 0.6020000 0.7103500 0.6260000 0.4320500 0.5723500
[4,] 0.5982500 0.7110500 0.6276000 0.4332500 0.5751000
```